# How to get&handle a list of objects in another class?

Tags: python, class, object

So I have a very simple "Customer" class which only stores the name and creates an id:

```
import secrets


class Customer:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_id(self):
        id = secrets.token_hex(20)
        return id
```

In another class my objective is to create a list where all the instances of Customer are stored and in all the functions in the class I need to handle either the name or the id of those customers.
The two methods I've found so far are import gc and do something like this

```
 for i in gc.get_objects():
      if isinstance(i, Customer):
           customer_list.append(i)
```

which I really dont understand and don't know if it works.

The other way I've found is to use getmembers(), but again I still have no idea about the syntax in using this function and how the name and the id will be stored.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is your other class responsible for creating these customer objects?

Comment: Absolutely would not recommend doing that at all, and you don't need to do that. There are three main methods to proceed: (1) register the customers into that class manually, (2) have a method on the other class that creates and appends the customer objects, or (3) during instance creation, register them with the other class (i.e. in `Customer.__new__`). Also can you give a more thorough example with another class so not everyone has to reference "the other class"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) In  the following example I demonstrate a way to store object instances in a class variable (list) and access them throught that list. b) I think that your method `get_id` returns different id every time is called, so considering that you want only one id per customer I suggest to create the id inside `__init__` and store it in a property.

```
import secrets

class Customer:

    objects = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.id = secrets.token_hex(20)
        Customer.objects.append(self)

Customer('A test')
Customer('B test')
Customer('C test')

for c in Customer.objects:
    print(c.name, c.id)
```